# Combining two Mux routers return 404

Tags: rest, go, gorilla, mux

I have two sub routers setup using Gorilla Mux in my first Go rest api application.

in user_api.go file, I have following route configuration.

```
func (userApi *UserApi) HandleUserEndpoints() *mux.Router {

    userRouter := mux.NewRouter().StrictSlash(true)
    userRouter.PathPrefix("/users").Subrouter()
    userRouter.HandleFunc("/create", userApi.newUser).Methods("POST")
    userRouter.HandleFunc("/get-all", userApi.allUsers).Methods("GET")
    userRouter.HandleFunc("/get/{id}", userApi.getUser).Methods("GET")
    userRouter.HandleFunc("/delete/{id}", userApi.deleteUser).Methods("DELETE")
    userRouter.HandleFunc("/update/{id}", userApi.updateUser).Methods("PUT")

    return userRouter
}
```

following is what is in my movie_api.go file

```
func (movieApi *MovieApi) HandleMovieEndpoints() *mux.Router {

    movieRouter := mux.NewRouter().StrictSlash(true)
    movieRouter.PathPrefix("/movies").Subrouter()
    movieRouter.HandleFunc("/get-all", movieApi.getAllMovies).Methods("GET")

    return movieRouter

}
```

In my app.go file, where I need to combine above two routers, I have combined them as below.

```
userEndpointsSubRouter := userApi.HandleUserEndpoints()
movieEndpointsSubRouter := movieApi.HandleMovieEndpoints()

router := mux.NewRouter().StrictSlash(true)

router.Handle("/users", userEndpointsSubRouter)
router.Handle("/movies", movieEndpointsSubRouter)

log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8002", router))
```

Now when I try to invoke an API, it returns me 404.

For example, I invoked the GET API to get all users.

```
curl --location --request GET 'http://localhost:8002/users/get-all'
```

This returns 404. I don't understand why.

Please show me how to do this correctly. Thanks

Comment: Try `userSubrouter := userRouter.PathPrefix("/users").Subrouter()` and use `userSubrouter` for registering the handlers.

Comment: As u suggested, I remvoed subrouter path from individual files and configured them in app.go file. Result is still the same

Comment: Try `router.Handle("/users/", userEndpointsSubRouter)`. i.e. `"/users"` will match only `"/users"`, but `"/users/"` should match any route that starts with `"/users/"`.

Comment: That alone was not enough. I somehow got it working. I had to make the router initialisation in the app.go file into ```router := http.NewServeMux()``` and use ```StripPrefix``` also.

```router.Handle("/users/", http.StripPrefix("/users", userEndpointsSubRouter))```

Comment: Sounds like you are now maybe returning the `userSubrouter` instead of the `userRouter`? Or you've made some other change that caused the different handler registration. What happens if you simply do something like [this](https://play.golang.org/p/EuBj6xu5ygh).

Comment: this is what I did.  https://play.golang.org/p/bn2bX-g4d4L